# how to count contacts based on their contact owner(users)

Tags: trigger

I want to count userwise contact records.when i will select one user and save it then in another field the number of contacts created by the particular user should reflect.

hello guys i want to count number of contacts based on their contact owners in another object benchmark__c.In this object name field is there which is look up to user. so i will select the user here and i want to get the record count in the field contact_count__c.Is this possible? how to do it?

```
trigger ContactProfileCount on Benchmark__c (after insert, after update) {
List<Benchmark__c> rbc= new List<Benchmark__c>();
List<Contact> con=new List<Contact>();
set<Id> appset = new set<Id>();
for( Benchmark__c a : Trigger.New){
     appset.add(a.Name__c);
 }
 //con=[select id,Name from Contact where OwnerId in: appset Group By OwnerId  ];   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An aggregate query should do what you need

> Get a set of owner Ids to limit the query to

```
AggregateResult[] ar = [
         Select Count(Id)cnt, OwnerId 
         From Contact 
         Where OwnerId IN :ownerIds 
         Group By OwnerId
];
```

Then you can put them in a collection

```
Map<Id,Integer> ownerCount = New Map<Id,Integer>();
for(AggregateResult result : ar)
     ownerCount.put( (Id)ar.get('OwnerId'), (Integer)ar.get('cnt'));
```

And use it as you need to

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger CountContact on Account (before update) {

    List<Contact> cntList=new List<Contact>();
    for(Account a:Trigger.New)
    {

            cntList=[Select Id from Contact where AccountId=:a.Id];
            a.CountContact__c=String.valueOf(cntList.size());

    }
    cntList.clear();
}
```